# jquery move li to ul

Tags: jquery, move

i have code:

```
<li><img src="" /></li>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Now, i want use jquery move `<li><img src="" /></li>` to ul, and position `<li>3</li>`

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li><img src="" /></li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: You can use insertAfter() check documentation here http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Comment: You shouldn't put `li` (list item) outside of a list (`ul`, `ol`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to give your `li` and `ul` a class like:

```
<li class="dummyLI"><img src="" /></li>
<ul class="dummyUL">......</ul>
```

then try this:

```
$('li.dummyLI').insertAfter('ul.dummyUL li:eq(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('li:has(img)').insertAfter('ul >li:eq(2)');
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TnLNm/)</kbd>

---

[.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li img").parent().insertAfter("ul li:eq(2)");
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/H4rD5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><img class="img" src="" /></li> <!-- added a class to the image -->
<!-- starting another `ul` without closing the previous one will generate invalid markup. You may either close the previous `ul` tag or insert the new `ul` tag before closing the above `li` -->
<ul class="list"> <!-- added a class to the `ul` -->
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>


function insertAfter(insertThis, insertTo) {
    $(insertThis).insertAfter(insertTo);
}

insertAfter(".img", ".list li:nth-child(2)");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nCf5L/